# GNU/Linux mirror display at lower resolution

Tags: display, resolution, mirror, clone

I'd like to mirror my primary display which is 2560x1440 to another monitor at 1920x1080. The other monitor is capable of up to 4k.

I have tried various xrandr commands and either the second screen automatically resizes to match the primary display or I end up with a box of the top corner of the primary display instead of a scaled mirror.

Another option I'm open to is using a virtual display and mirroring to that (if that is at all possible).

The reason I want to do this is that I record my screen to make coding tutorials. If I record at my working resolution of 2560x1440 then viewers sometimes struggle to see what I'm doing if they are using smaller screens. So I want to screen capture a lower resolution display while I continue to work on my primary monitor.

Comment: mirroring the full screen at a lower resolution necessarily involves scaling, so you'll just be seeing what they already see. you probably want to just crop the screen in post if you're intent on using screen-recordings

Comment: Do you know Xvnc ?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Tell me more...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing I thought you could run a vncviewer on the other monitor. You scale it , well, to any resolution you like.

Comment: @GerardH.Pille Intesting idea, I'll look into it

Comment: I'm afraid the last time I used this, was in the previous century. But it was very helpful in teaching students the use of a complex tool.